# bit layout of vector after bitcasting in llvm

Tags: c++, vector, llvm

```
%0 = bitcast i16 %arg1 to <2 x i8>
%2 = extractelement <2 x i8> %0, i32 1
```

`%arg1` in memory:

```
 00000000  11111111

|--8bit--||--8bit--|
```

After bitcasting, `%0` is a pointer to vector.

So is `%0` also the address of the first element of the vector?

And what is `%2` exactly? Is it the second element of `vector(11111111)` or,
`00000000`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`bitcast <type1> <value> to <type2>`](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#bitcast-to-instruction) converts the `value`, `%arg1` in your case, from `type1` to `type2` without changing the bits given that the number of bits in the two types are the same.

```
%0 = bitcast i16 %arg1 to <2 x i8>
```

This means that `%0` is now an array/vector of two 8-bit integers instead of a single 16-bit integer.  Looking over the linked documentation, this appears to only be a value.

[`extractelement <n x <type>> <value>, i32 <index>`](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#extractelement-instruction) extracts the element in the `n`-length array of `type`d `value`s as the given `type` using the 32-bit integer `index`.

```
%2 = extractelement <2 x i8> %0, i32 1
```

This means that `%2` is now an 8-bit integer with the value of element 1 (the second/last 8-bit element).  Assuming little endian hardware, I would expect the value of `%2` to be `0`.

Comment: You have two mistakes here: first, you write that "`%0` is an array/vector" - while it is clearly a vector, not an array. Also, the `extractelement` is a value of type `i8`, not `i32` - the `i32` is the type of the index.

Comment: The vector is logically being treated like an array, which is why I referenced it with the slash. Good catch on the 32-bit versus 8-bit; I definitely misread the documentation on that one.

Answer (score 1):

After bitcasting, `%0` is a `Value` of type `<2 x i8>`. It is not "a pointer". The vector may very well be stored in a register when code generation to machine code happens.

`%2` is `i8`, because `extractelement` is defined as:

```
<result> = extractelement <n x <ty>> <val>, i32 <idx>    ; yields <ty>
```

The vector has two elements, each with of type `i8`. `%2` is a `Value` that holds the second element in the vector.

Note that how the vector is laid out in memory or registers is target dependent. LLVM IR level doesn't care about that. It sees the vector as an abstract container of two values.

Answer (score 1):

(Would like to post this despite this question was discussed fairly long time ago, after reading [when it's good to reply an old question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379234/when-is-it-bad-to-answer-an-old-question), since the reply provides another way to verify the answer and references recent document update)

The value of %2 would depend on the endianess and target (the vector 's memory layout depends on the target and endianess as Eli Bendersky mentioned); https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/vfcGhb4EK could be a good way to visualize that.

---

By reading the language reference, these two are helpful to reason about the above IR (at least to me)

1. [the semantics of bitcast](https://reviews.llvm.org/D94964)
2. [the memory layout of vector types](https://reviews.llvm.org/D94964)

Both 1 and 2 were updated from https://reviews.llvm.org/D94964 (credit to the authors and reviewers)